# SDL Load image using multiple classes and files

Tags: c++, image, sdl

I've been using SDL for a little awhile and following Lazy Foo's tutorials. I have no problem loading images, animating sprites etc... but when I attempt to separate functions into different header files I'm unable to load an image.
I've looked about for on the internet for a few days now but haven't found an answer.

Sprite.cpp

```
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Globals.h"

using namespace Globals;

Graphics sprite;

Sprite::Sprite(){}

bool Sprite::load()
{
    bool success = true;
    if(!sprite.loadImage("C:/SDL_Project/bin/Debug/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"))
    {
        printf("Failed to load image!\n");
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

void Sprite::renderSprite()
{
    SDL_Rect* curSprite = &spriteClips[frames];
    sprite.renderImage((SCREEN_WIDTH - curSprite->w) / 2, (SCREEN_HEIGHT - curSprite->h) / 2, curSprite);
}
```

Graphics.cpp

```
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Globals.h"

using namespace Globals;

Graphics::Graphics()
{
        hei = 0;
        wid = 0;
        texture = NULL;

    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Foo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                           SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    if(win && ren == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create Window & Renderer!\n");
    }
    else
    {


        int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
        if( !(IMG_Init(imgFlags) &imgFlags))
        {
            printf("Image flags not initiated!\n");
        }
    }
}

Graphics::~Graphics(){}

SDL_Texture* Graphics::loadImage(std::string file)
{
    SDL_Texture* newTxtr = NULL;
    image = IMG_Load(file.c_str());
    if(image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to load image\n");
    }
    else
    {
            newTxtr = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, image);
            if(newTxtr == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to create texture!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                wid = image->w;
                hei = image->h;
            }
            SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    }
    texture = newTxtr;
    return texture;
}

void Graphics::free()
{
    if(texture != NULL)
    {
        texture = NULL;
        wid = 0;
        hei = 0;
    }
}

void Graphics::renderImage(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip)
{
    SDL_Rect dstClip = {x, y, wid, hei};

    if(clip != NULL)
    {
        dstClip.w = clip->w;
        dstClip.h = clip->h;
    }
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, texture, clip, &dstClip);
}

void Graphics::render()
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);
}

void Graphics::clearScreen()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
}



SDL_Renderer* Graphics::getRenderer()
{
    return ren;
}

void Graphics::closeGraphics()
{
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
}
```

GameLoop.cpp

```
#include "GameLoop.h"
#include "Graphics.h"
#include "Sprite.h"

GameLoop::GameLoop()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)< 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to init\n");
    }
    else
    {
        this->loop();
    }
}

GameLoop::~GameLoop(){}

void GameLoop::loop()
{
    Graphics graphics;

    SDL_Event e;

    bool quit = false;

    while(!quit)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!= 0)
        {
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;

            }

        }
        this->renderGraphics(graphics);
    }
    this->close(graphics);
}
void GameLoop::loadSprite()
{
    Sprite sp;
    sp.renderSprite();
}

void GameLoop::renderGraphics(Graphics& graphics)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(graphics.ren, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        graphics.clearScreen();
        graphics.render();
}

void GameLoop::close(Graphics& graphics)
{
    SDL_Quit();
    graphics.closeGraphics();
}
```

I've included all but one of the .cpp files.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand what do you mean. Even if you're not asking to fix your code, maybe a little code-context will be more that useful. Try to add to your question a *minimal* code example (just the problem part).

Comment: Do not include unnecessary information in question. For example, Sorry for the lengthy post in advance. I'm no expert at C++, etc. Concentrate on the problem statement and try to explain what you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: There isn't an error which is the real issue because I'm not sure how to address the problem, I've now included the code and began putting in SDL_Error() and Image_GetError() to see if they can help me find anything possibly an invalid renderer etc

Comment: What's in your `globals.h`? Why your `Sprite::load` loads image into global object (it never called in presented code, neither is `GameLoop::loadSprite` - may be that is your problem)? Having load and rendering in the same function is also might be problemmatic as you'll load it on every draw.

Comment: Globals currently includes `SCREEN_WIDTH` & `SCREEN_HEIGHT` and I'll try organizing the code a little better, I was worried something like that could have been the problem and that maybe I'm just being an idiot and not declaring functions in the Game Loop or something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The code you posted never calls `GameLoop::loadSprite()`, which I assume is the problem. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see understand what is executed? Alternatively, you could print out debug statements in some of the loader methods and see what is called that way.